# how to unserialize array in php-wp?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i am trying `get_post_meta($post_id,'meta_key_here',true);`
into my data base the meta_key contains value 
 -->

```
a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:10:"Directions";s:2:"id";s:14:"tab-directions";s:7:"content";s:422:"<strong>Custom fields </strong> can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.
 <ul>
  <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>

</ul>";s:15:"tooltip_content";s:13:"tooltip dataa";}i:1;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:18:"Directions for use";s:2:"id";s:22:"tab-directions-for-use";s:7:"content";s:736:"<strong>Custom fields </strong> can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.
 <ul>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
  <a href=""><strong>Custom fields </strong> can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.
 <ul>
  <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
   <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
  Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme. </a>";s:15:"tooltip_content";s:15:"tooltip dataa 2";}i:2;a:4:{s:5:"title";s:25:"super charged ingredients";s:2:"id";s:29:"tab-super-charged-ingredients";s:7:"content";s:413:"<strong>Custom fields </strong> can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.
<ul>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>
 <li>Custom fields can be used to add extra metadata to a post that you can use in your theme.</li>";s:15:"tooltip_content";s:15:"tooltip dataa 3";}}
```

When i try this

```
`$my_data=unserialize($data); 
 print_r($my_data);`
```

it displays nothing.(empty array).
(i want to fetch the tooltip_content against specific postid from this serialized array.)

Comment: can you post a simpler example with less code? There's a lot of fluff here that's not needed to demonstrate the problem

Comment: Your data is not unserializable. What was the source of that data?

Answer (score 0):

Provided value is invalid. If you try to unserialize it, you'll get `false` and notice: `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 518 of 2043 bytes`.

And `print_r(false)` doesn't print anything, you can use `var_dump` for more accurate debugging